# substituting a numeric vector with symbolic defined function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I've got this problem to solve for a very long time,and unfortunately ,still couldn't find a proper answer for it.and here is the problem:
I have this piece of code which is producing a string with 'syms' function and requesting from user to enter his/her desired function in 'x(i)' form:

```
start=input('Enter Starting Point In A Vector Form:\n');
N = input('How many variables Your Function Has?\n');
strArray = [ repmat('x',N,1) dec2base(1:N,10) repmat(' ',N,1)]; % create strings
strArray = strvcat(regexprep(mat2cell(strArray, ...
  ones(1,size(strArray,1)), size(strArray,2)),'x0+','x')).'; % remove heading 0's
str = ['syms ' strArray(:).']; % string to be evaluated
display(str);
eval(str);
f=input('Enter Your Desired Function In The Form Of x(i) Variables;eg:x1^2 etc:\n');
```

Now,I want to assign the 'start' vector to this symbolic function 'f'.how can i do so?

Comment: subs(f,symvar(f),start)

Comment: What does it mean to "assign a vector to a function"?

Comment: Dear Luis,I want to assign a vector to a multidimensional function.for example,suppose you have a 3-dimensional vector [1 2 3],and a 3-dimensional function f(x1,x2,x3)=x1+x2+x3. how do you assign(substitute) the vector to the function?

Comment: Dear Pawel,your guidance was really useful.it could solve my problem.many thanks bro.